# Refresh an imageview in android with an image I got on background

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, background, imageview

My question concerns this thread- 
[How to refresh imageview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703407/how-to-refresh-imageview-in-android)

Im too trying to get an image via socket, decode it, and setting it on an imageview.
The socket need to stay open in case another image will be sent and then ill update the imageview again.

I didnt got the part when in the other thread they response not to do it in the main thread.

From the main activity I should open a new thread which will be 'stuck' on "while (true)"
so it can keep listening to up coming images, and when ever a full image had sent, it needs to update the imageview.
But the imageview is in the main thread (main thread equals UI thread?) so its starting to be a bit problematic for me...

Any one?

// ADDED - 
this is the asyncTask I had -

```
public class AsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
 private DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
 private ImageView iv = null;

 public RobotMapAsyncTask(DataInputStream dataStream, ImageView imageView) {
     dataInputStream = dataStream;
     iv = imageView;
 }

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] byteChunk = new byte[1024];
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    int c;

    if (dataInputStream != null) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                byteChunk = new byte[1024];
                while ((c = dataInputStream.read(byteChunk)) != -1){
                    buffer.write(byteChunk, 0, c);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteChunk, 0, byteChunk.length);

            if (bitmap != null) {
                //runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    //public void run() {
                        //iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    //}
               // }); 
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

but then I obvious cant call runOnUiThread because this is not an activity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the image of your ImageView in a Runnable launched by `Activity.runOnUIThread(Runnable)`  or `Handler.post(Runnable)`

Comment: wait. On the main activity, in the onCreate() method I start the background thread which get am image. from thie background thread I should run another runnable as you metioned and update the imageView?

Comment: yes, this runnable will be run on the UI Thread so your ImageView will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

After you get a new image, call this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            imView.setBackgroundResource(yourResource);
        }
    });
```

Just make the obvious changes to fit your code

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways:

a) one way is invoke a worker thread using handler and runnable from main thread which does the fetching and decoding of images. Once you have the decoded image, just set the imageview from your worker thread

b) Alternatively, you can use the async task feature of android to fetch images and update the imageview on main thread

Comment: just return a bitmap in doinbackground method and add a method onPostExecute which takes Bitmap as a parameter and inside this method, set you imageview to this bitmap

Comment: but as you said - I need to somehow refresh the UI thread so Ill see the change (@VinceFR suggest the runOnUIThread or post but this is not an activity nor handler). and more important - when I return the doInBackground the aSyncTask ends. I need to keep on listening ti the socket for another and another images.. I dont want to return and go to onPostExecute...